# raspbian cmake erorr when install open cv in rapsberry pi

Tags: raspbian, opencv

I want install open cv and when step using cmake I get stucked.

here the error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Core.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core" with any
  of the following names:




Qt5CoreConfig.cmake

qt5core-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Core" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Core_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Core" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Is there any important reason why you try to install OpenCV from sources by compiling it?

Comment: Did you try to do what the error message tells you to do?

Comment: i have final project to use mobilnet ssd for vehicle detection  and need opencv  i am really newbie and dont know what it is mean and how to fix it i still dont know , i alredy instal qt5 with sudo and it is already installed but still error when i want compile open cv

Answer (score 0):

**Installing the under-listed packages may fix your problem.**

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev

sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev
```